# Java MyBatis Call a custom function in mapper to get secure information receive Error Oracle ORA-00904

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have a function secureUser.collection.getExampleId. This function returns an Example Id given a keyId. I am attempting to call this in a MyBatis mapper.

```
<mapper namespace="core.namespace.dao.mybatis.MyMapper">
   <resultMap id="Data" type="core.model.impl.table">
      <result column="column1" property="one" />
      <result column="column2" property="two" />
      <result column="column3" property="three" />
      <result column="secure" property="sec" />
   </resultMap>

   <select id="getSecure" parameterType="java.lang.Long" resultMap="Data">
      select column1, column2, column3, secureUser.collection.getExampleId(#{id}) secure
      from mytable mt
      where mt.keyId = #{id}
   </select>
</mapper>
```

When this code is called I receive an error ORA-00904: "SECUREUSER"."COLLECTION"."GETEXAMPLEID": invalid identifier. I ran this code in PL/SQL as written above and it works fine and return the correct data. After looking at the error I attempted to run the above code with the "'s around the secureUser, collection and getExampleId. When I ran that I received the same error that I was receiving from Java ORA-00904 so I figured that Java is putting the quotes around those values in the select statement.

How would I call this Oracle function secureUser.collection.getExampleId(#{id}) secure?

This is work data so I had to change all of the object names.

Comment: If possible, stop using dot `.` in identifiers. It just makes things unnecessarily complicated. If you cannot change the identifier, you have to enclose the identifier with double quotes. i.e. `... , column3 , "SECUREUSER.COLLECTION.GETEXAMPLEID"(#{id}) from ...`. Note that the cases must match the actual identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to apologize. The above does work. The function name was changed in the database. That was the issue with the Invalid Identifier message.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL is case-insensitive by default. When you use quotation marks, you're forcing case sensitivity, so if the objects weren't created *exactly* the same way, with quotation marks in the original DDL, they won't be found. Your only option if you can't suppress the quotes is to make every label in the code upper case, as this is Oracle's default presentation.

```
SECUREUSER.COLLECTION.GETEXAMPLEID(#{id})
```

Comment: I updated the error message I received in this question. I also changed the code in the Mapper to contain all caps as suggested. I received the same ORA-00904 error. Do you know of a way or a setting in Java that would prevent Java from surrounding the SECUREUSER.COLLECTION.GETEXAMPLEID with quotes?

Comment: The actual function name is SECUREUSER.collection.getexampleid. It appears when java/MyBatis runs the code there are double quotes placed around each identifier and each identifier is converted to all upper case. In the code there are no double quotes and the capitalization matches the exact capitalization of each character in the function create code.